# How to properly access a malloced struct?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, access-violation, dereference

I want to creat a struct instance by alocating memory on the heap, not as a variable on the stack. When I try to go to one of the members of the dereferenced pointer to the alocated memory, I get an access violation exeption thrown.

I did not include stdlib.h, only stdio.h, and that was the problem, but the code was compiled and no errors where thrown.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct shell {
    int num;
};

int main()
{
    struct shell* p;
    p = (struct shell*) malloc(sizeof(struct shell));
    (*p).num = 2; //exception thrown

    return 0;
}
```

At first I tried the arrow operator but I switched to dereferencing to simplify, but it still doesn't work. I've seen some examples on the internet and they seem to be very similar to my code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What warnings is the compiler giving you? Is it telling you to #include <stdlib.h>? Your code is 'correct' other than that. Although the -> operator is more natural.

Comment: This should work fine. The only time when it won't work is if you exceed some memory limit and malloc returns NULL (I guarantee you - this doesn't happen in this program)

Comment: `printf("%p\n", p);` - it's not null, or 0, is it?

Comment: also you don't need `(struct shell*)` in C

Comment: Opinions might vary whether using `(*p).` is simpler than `p->`. But unless you get a `NULL` pointer from `malloc` your code should not crash

Comment: " but the code was compiled and no errors where thrown" No it wasn't, not without warnings. [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277340) If you wish to block the compiler from generating a binary out of invalid C, then follow [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not #include <stdlib.h>, the compiler had to guess at what malloc() returns, and it will guess that it returns an int, which is 32 bits on many systems. malloc() actually returns a pointer, which is 64 bits on many systems. This is likely the cause of the problem.

<del>(It will also guess that malloc() takes no parameters.)</del>

As mentioned by others in the comments, you don't need to cast the return value from malloc(), but you should check that it didn't return NULL.

If your compiler did not generate any warnings, tell it to generate more. For gcc, you might add -Wall -Wextra.

Comment: A standard C compiler isn't allowed to let this code through without diagnostic messages. gcc doesn't, even in the default "sloppy mode".

Comment: "(It will also guess that malloc() takes no parameters.)" No. Back in ancient C90 is would assume that the argument is of type int.

Comment: Updated to remove bogus info - thanks.